# PDF image soft mask artifacts

Tags: pdf, artifacts

I am developing a PDF generator by using c++.

During in process, i have faced a big problem with image soft mask.

[image]

I put an image right side of PDF page as like above. The pink bear is a bitmap image and has alpha channel. However, it has not PDF mask yet.

After i succeed to put an image right way. i need to find a way to remove black background of the image. (a.k.a alpha processing)

I found that there are several options to archive it as like below.

- monochrome mask.
- stencil mask.
- soft mask.

My application has gradient images. Therefore, the soft mask method was the best for me. So, i implemented it as like below.

[image]

The black background of image was gone. It seems all things are good.

However, i realized that there is some artifacts when i zoomed in the result.

[image]

Left side is correct image with its alpha, right side is PDF result.

There are black noise around outlines of the bear.(click the image to show larger) When i put a rectangle image, i could find black lines around edge.

It seems like that RGB channels and A channel is not matched exactly.(It seems like A channels is bigger by 1~2 px)

I implement it as like below.

1. I made an XObject (SMask)

```
8 0 obj
<<
/Type /XObject
/Subtype /Image
/Width 693
/Height 972
/BitsPerComponent 8
/Filter /FlateDecode
/ColorSpace /DeviceGray
/Length 137856
>>
stream
```

2. Linked the XObject to orignal image.

```
7 0 obj
<<
/Type /XObject
/Subtype /Image
/Width 693
/Height 972
/BitsPerComponent 8
/Filter /FlateDecode
/ColorSpace /DeviceRGB
/SMask 8 0 R
/Length 261436
>>
stream
```

That is all i did. Do i have to do more things?

I spent a week to fix it. But, i still do not have any ideas even though i searched on google.

I attach the result file.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/09ggj28bhzi8f6e/Output.pdf?dl=0

Please, somebody give me piece of advice.

---

**** UPDATE  ****

I made more simple version for testing.

[image]

I made a bitmap. And i drew a white rectangle left side of the image as like above. Right side is empty.

[image]

After putting the bitmap on PDF and applying soft mask by its alpha values,
there is a black line at the edge of white rectangle. (Left side is drawn white rectangle. Right side is transparent.)

The bitmap's alpha channel is absolutely the same with above image. I have checked it on Photoshop. There is not any grey color in alpha channel and exactly matched with RGB channels each pixels.

[image]

I attach the PDF result.

[Before soft masking](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l6mk557zapx98x3/rectangle-wo.pdf?dl=0)

[After soft masking](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xbgwix5mnh9tizc/rectangle-o.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: All the PDF parts look fine, it appears to be an issue largely with how you separate the original image to generate the soft mask. I observed the artifacts coming and going at certain zoom levels, so it implies you have the edges between the two images to thin. Perhaps you need an overlap of some sort. Or perhaps increase/decrease anti-aliasing so the edges are not so abrupt.

Comment: @Ryan Thank you for comment. When i draw a rectangle to bitmap and put the image on pdf, i could see black lines at edge of rectangle. It looks like those are not that same size or It could be a blend mode problem. Am i doing correctly? I am new as PDF generating programmer, so i am still confusing whether i am missing something or not.

Comment: I suggest you do the following. Make a version of your PDF where image "I1" has no SMask entry. And then another version, where you delete/rename "I1", and rename "I2" to "I1". Then you have two PDF files and you can compare the soft mask and the image itself. You can see it has very busy edges, that could confuse a rendering engine. I think you just want to simplify the image edges. The PDF standard does not always describe exact pixel placement.

Comment: @Ryan Thank you for advice. This problems is driving me crazy.

Comment: As an unrelated aside: Your PDF generator currently generates broken cross reference tables (entries are 19 bytes long, should be 20) and trailer **Size** entries (too small by 1).

Comment: @mkl Thank you for the mention. I have omitted space each end of line. Unfortunately, it is the same result even though i fixed the table.

Comment: Yes, that's why I called my remark *unrelated* ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question seems pretty old but still incase someone stumbles upon it, I had a similar issue of thin grey lines appearing around transparent image edges and found out that the issue comes because of **"image smoothing"** by the PDF viewer. To confirm, you can open the document in Adobe Acrobat Reader and turn off image smoothing from preferences, the lines will go away - but since it's viewer-dependent, can't rely on this solution.

After going through the pdf specification a bunch of times to make sure the alpha was being split correctly and a lot of online searches, I figured the issue was that the transparent pixels were actually **"transparent black"** or rgba(0,0,0,0) and so the viewer naturally tries to blend the colours on the edge creating a grey line. I was using an image generated from the browser and browsers treat any pixel with alpha=0 as "transparent black". Some more details given in these GitHub issues: [#issue1](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1864) [#issue2](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1625) but the solution mentioned, to convert the pixels to "transparent white" rgba(255,255,255,0), would cause the same issue if the background and image were changed to black.

I don't have much knowledge about image-smoothing/anti-aliasing algorithms but I ***changed the RGB colour of every fully transparent pixel to an average of the surrounding pixels and the artefacts went away!(keep alpha at 0)*** Running the averaging function a few times will give more smoother results and since they are transparent pixels, the accuracy of smoothing isn't as important either as long as there isn't a hard edge being produced.

This was just a test run and there are probably better and much faster image smoothing options out there. imgData is your RGB pixel stream and alphaChannel is the soft mask

```
let iterations = 10;
  
  while (iterations > 0) {
    let p = 0,
        a = 0;
    
    for (a = 0; a < pixelCount; a++) {
      if (alphaChannel[a] !== 0) {
        p += colorCount;
        continue;
      }
      const colorSum = {r: 0, g: 0, b: 0};

      let count = 0;
      for (i = -2; i < 3; i++) {
        for (let j = -2; j < 3; j++) {
          const index = (a + i + j * this.width) * colorCount;
          if (index < 0 || index >= this.width * this.height * colorCount) {
            continue
          }
          colorSum.r += imgData[index];
          colorSum.g += imgData[index + 1];
          colorSum.b += imgData[index + 2];
          count++;
        }
      }
      imgData[p++] = colorSum.r / count;
      imgData[p++] = colorSum.g / count;
      imgData[p++] = colorSum.b / count;

    }
    iterations--;
  }
```